# Error The name 'inumber' does not exist in the current context - How does it not exist?

Tags: c#

I was programming a C# program, where I got this error"

Error   1   The name 'inumber' does not exist in the current context

for this line

```
Console.WriteLine(iNumber + "/" + i + "=" + d);
```

Looking over the code, I don't understand how inumber doesn't exist. I understand what the error means, but for iNumber to not exists, then the try catch would have failed, meaning that code that had the error wouldnt run...

Could someone explain to me why iNumber won't exist?

```
 try
            {
                iNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                for (int i = 1; i < iNumber; i++)
                {
                    decimal d;
                    d = iNumber / i;


                    if (((d % 1) == 0))
                    {
                        if (!NumberCount.Contains(d))
                        {
                            NumberCount.Add(d);
                            Console.WriteLine(iNumber + "/" + i + "=" + d);
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of iNumber?

Comment: You forgot to declare iNumber. This is compile-time error, not run-time one.

Comment: I have declare iNumber - this was an error on VS - once i c&p the line, it had no issues

Comment: Swallowing all exceptions is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @GarethJones, if you have declared it somewhere then include that in your code example.

Comment: Part of declaring a variable is giving it a type.  Your code (that you've shown) never does that.

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a error on my part - I had thought I got the declare in my copying of the code, but had not - its declared right before the try catch

Comment: @GarethJones: Then what is your question?

Comment: Side-note: you can use `Console.WriteLine` in a more readable way, change `Console.WriteLine(iNumber + "/" + i + "=" + d);` to `Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", iNumber, i, d);`. Also: empty catch blocks are evil ( except when used with empty try blocks ).

Comment: @SLaks Theres isnt one - I have flagged the question for deletion

Comment: Which I cant do with answers on the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **compiler error**.
Your code isn't running at all.

`catch` blocks only handle *exceptions* that are thrown at **runtime**.

---

As the error *clearly* states, you never declared `iNumber` anywhere.

Comment: You've been really annoyed at people not reading error messages lately, huh.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
iNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

to this:

```
int iNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Right now you are acting as if `iNumber` was already declared somewhere.  Based on the code you have shown us it was not.